# android ndk: How to access third part shared library

Tags: android-ndk

I have a third part shared library (.so) with some classes (C++). I would like to use this library in my Android App. I am planning to write a piece of code in C++ too, for access third part shared library. The code that access third part shared library will be put in a shared library to (mySHaredLibrary.so). My doubt is how to compile  mySHaredLibrary.so, how I can indicate in my make file that mySHaredLibrary.so depends on  third part shared library.

I am using android ndk r10d for windows 64 bits. (https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the external lib is called *libThirdParty.so*, and you have .h headers you include from your sources to use it. Here is what you can do:

Place your .so files for each architectures under `jni/ThirdPartyLib/<abi>` (Android ABIs supported by the NDK right now are *armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64, arm64-v8a, mips, mips64*). You should have at least one version of your lib for armeabi or armeabi-v7a and for x86, and it's of course better to have one for all of the supported architectures.

Then, place your .h files under `jni/ThirdPartyLib/include`

Now, here is what you can have inside your Makefiles:

**Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# ThirdParty prebuilt
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ThirdParty
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ThirdPartyLib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libThirdParty.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ThirdPartyLib/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Your lib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mySHaredLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source1.cpp source2.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ThirdParty
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI := all # can be "armeabi-v7a x86 mips..." depending on what you support.
APP_PLATFORM := android-14 # should be the same number than in Android project's minSdkVersion.
```

Comment: How to add APP_PLATFORM in build.gradle? I do not have Application.mk file.

Comment: You don't, stable ndk support in gradle is now using cmake: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html